# Converting MXD file to earlier version/release?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, convert

I upgraded from 10.0 to 10.1 for a few days.  Due to conflicts with other packages, i had to downgrade back to 10.0.  Now I cannot open any .mxd file I opened with 10.1.

I did not create any with 10.1, they were all 10.0 mxds that ArcGIS "upgraded" for me, so it's not an issue of unsupported features.

How can I "downgrade" the mxds?  10.0's MXD Doctor can't find any layeres in the MXDs opened and saved with 10.1.

Comment: use the 'Save A Copy' command from the ArcMap File menu to save each map document in an older version.

Comment: @Mapperz wouldn't he have to do that from 10.1, though? He's already downgraded.

Comment: Could you imagine the worldwide uproar that would ensue if, say, each upgrade of Word or Excel--even minor ones--produced documents unreadable by the current version?  (I think this is a fair comparison because ESRI's leadership has often, over a long time, compared its software to Microsoft.)

Comment: you can run both on one pc - through virtual box of course.

Answer (score 6):

The help files for 10.1 indicate [how to save a copy to previous versions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000253000000) which may not resolve your issue now.
The missing link issue may be related to broken paths if relative pathnames were not used.
Perhaps these can be re-established.
[image: savacopy]

Comment: Robert may need to reinstall 10.1 long enough to save the MXDs as 10.0 versions (as linked in this answer).

Comment: definately will have to install 10.1 to use the saveas. and there is no side by side install allowed!!! Vote http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000btA8AAI  And you can also search ideas for "install version"

Comment: GeoKevin - Uninstalling/Installing is virtually an entire day.                                                                  Brad - Since Arc (10.0) is "integrated" in another package (which had the conflict) I think I'm screwed until they upgrade.  to 10.1, maybe in the fall.